# C arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Just started to learn C language.
I have a pointer array int *parr and I need to fill it with random numbers and then do some other things with it.
But I even don't understand how to fill it with random numbers. I tried something like this, but it hangs the program:

```
for(i=0 ; i<R ; i++)
{
  for(j=0 ; j<C; j++)
    {
    *(parr+i*C+j)=rand() % 10;
    printf("%d",*(parr+i*C+j));
    }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you done it with a one-dimensional array?

Comment: the key to this problem lies in how parr is defined and initialized, so please add that bit of code as well.

Comment: You need to post the entire code with declaration and allocation of `parr`.

Comment: Did you malloc() the memory?   You need to malloc R*C * sizeof int.

Comment: Now I understand that the problem was that I didn't know how to initialize the array correctly.
After initializing with malloc the programm is working and all the functions, I have written, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you initialize it, you probably have to `malloc` memory like this:

```
parr = malloc(R * C * sizeof(*parr));
```

Comment: Is it just me or will this dereference an uninitialized pointer?

Answer (score 2):

```
int *parr;
```

just defines a pointer to a n integer, but there's no storage associated with it.  You could either

```
int parr[sizeofarray];
```

or

```
int *parr = calloc (sizeofarray, sizeof(int));
```

to obtain the right amount of storage.

based on your example sizeofarray should be at least `R * C`.

Comment: It should be: R * C * sizeof(int)

Comment: @Roee no, because I use sizeofarray either as a size argument for the int array, or in calloc as nelem parameter.  calloc != malloc